# Am I looking for a cross join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have two tables:

```
id_table     entry_table
--------     -----------
 [Id]         [entries]
  1             a
  2             b
  3             c
  4             d
  5
```

Is there a way to select the results into another table where I get:

```
select_results
--------------
[Id] [entries]
1     a
2     b
3     c
```

I'm trying e.g.

```
Select top 3 * from id_table, entry_table
```

and vice versa, but that gives:

```
1  a
1  b
1  c
```

These two tables SHOULD have the same amount of entries but I'm using "top 3" at the minute to see if it's possible.

**Maybe I need a cross join with a where clause?**

Comment: use order by then rank()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` and then use join

```
select a.*,b.* from
(select *,row_number() over(order by Id) rn1
from id_table
)  a  
join     
(select *,row_number() over(order by entries) rn1
from entry_table
) b on a.rn=b.rn1
```

Comment: I'd seen a query similar to this at some point but didn't know how to search for it.This seems to work awesome on preliminary test, I'll accept this in 8 minutes when it lets me!

Comment: Haha sorry, got pulled into meeting and only just finalised this, it works perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `row_number()` window analytic function with `top` keyword as

```
select top 3   
       [Id], [entries]
  from id_table i
  join ( select row_number() over (order by [entries]) as row_id, 
                [entries]
           from entry_table ) e
    on i.[Id]=e.row_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=17feda420534beb318d5fdb4dcf62885)</kbd>